# Php include function mess char encoding

Tags: php, character-encoding, include

i have a file teste.php with

```
<?php

echo "descrição";

?>
```

When i call this teste.php directly, it prints everything ok,

but when a call another file that include('teste.php') it prints unrecognized characters. it seems to me that include function mess up with char enconding. isn't it? Can someone help me!!

Comment: Can you post both files completely please. Both should be set to UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Treffynnon, you are right, one of my files has iso enconding and the other has utf. i already change its enconding, and now it works! Thank alot.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark the answer I have added below as the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Set both files to UTF-8 encoding to solve the issue.

Comment: A note to this is the PHP utf8_encode function is very easy to resolve this problem without having to change all files, it is also handy when dealing with multiple languages from a database ;)